# Vue.js change class on mounted

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a button element with a .hover property and I need the hover animation to also happen as soon as the page is mounted. How can I attribute a class to a button on the mounted function and then disattribute it?

I was thinking of using a setTimeout but it's not working properly. I'm basing my code off of this codePen: https://codepen.io/lucasfads/pen/QWwjGjv

```html
<a href="#" class="button" id="specialButton">
  <span class="icon"></span>
  <span class="text">Hakuna Matata</span>
</a>
```

```js
mounted() {
  document.getElementById("specialButton").classList.add("expanded");

  setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById("specialButton").classList.remove("expanded");
  }, 3000);
}
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: #099;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 60px;
  height: 32px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow:hidden;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 32px;
  transition: max-width 0.5s;
}

.button:hover,
.button .expanded {
  max-width: 300px;
}

.icon {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  padding: 0px 8px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: if you're using `document.getElementById` in a vue project, it usually means you're doing vuejs wrong - usually, you'd have something like `:class="someVariable"` (note, the leasing `:`) and change the value of `someVariable` - no need for `document.get*` at all - can you explain in what way *it's not working properly* ... what happens? what should happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `.button.expanded` not `.button .expanded`

Other than that, see a comment from Jaromanda X, I agree that using direct DOM manipulations in Vue is a bad indicator.

Another thought - it'll probably be more efficient to have that class by default, and then remove it later. Otherwise you mount, add class, remove class - 3 DOM operations. Instead you can just mount, remove class - 2 DOM operations.

Comment: I can't believe I missed the whitespace between the classes, thank you so much! And I'll definitely look into the idea of having only 2 DOM operations

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at following snippet (Vue way, no need to get element ):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      initBtn: true
    }
  },
  mounted() {
   setTimeout(() => this.initBtn = false, 3000);
  }
})
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: #099;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 60px;
  height: 32px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow:hidden;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 32px;
  transition: max-width 0.5s;
}

.button:hover,
.button.expanded {
  max-width: 300px;
}

.icon {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  padding: 0px 8px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <a href="#" class="button" :class="initBtn && 'expanded'">
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span class="text">Hakuna Matata</span>
  </a>
</div>
```